# Jquery UI tab not working in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I am using jquery UI tab in angularJS and used ng-repeat to generate list items and tab containers. Tabs are working but the tab containers are not working properly.

**template - tabs.html**

```
<ul ng-sortable="pages">
    <li ng-controller="pageCtrl" ng-repeat="page in pages">
        <a class="pageName" href="#{{page.id}}">{{page.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="{{page.id}}" ng-repeat="page in pages">
    <p>{{page.id}}</p>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('ngTabs', function($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: "js/templates/tabs.html",
            link: function(scope, elm) {
                elm.tabs();
            }
        };
    })
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sannitesh/NLw6y/

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I'm confused by the Fiddle.  What's not working right with the JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the ngTabs directive is executed the content of that div is not generated yet. Wrapping the call to .tabs() in a setTimeout will do the trick.

```
myApp.directive('ngTabs', function() {
    return function(scope, elm) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            elm.tabs();
        },0);
    };
});
```

see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLw6y/32/). This might not be the best way/the angular way.

You could take a look at the [compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) service especially if the actual tabs change at runtime.

Comment: Should he not be using the $timeOut service?

Comment: @uriDium If he wants to trigger a $scope.$apply then yes but if it's a purely visual effect then there is no need, the directive is not modifying scope data so there is nothing to apply

Comment: I just thought that $timeout was guaranteed to execute outside of any digest or apply phases and immediately after the current phase is completed. I just thought it was safer.

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout it's actually the opposite :). After looking in the 1.2.0rc1 codebase it seems it takes a third parameter invokeApply(defaults to true) besides the 2 normal timeout params: fn and delay. So in order to mimic the setTimeout functionality but still call $timeout you need $timeout(fn, 0, false)